# How do we share our xamarin app?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

we are developing a dating-like app and we need to share our app on other social media. We've been trying to use Firebase Dynamic Links to do this (since App Invites only work with Email and SMS) but we got stuck because there's no Nuget Package for Xamarin.Android.

We are creating the dynamic link, but our issue is that if the user that clicks on this link doesn't have the app installed, after he installs the app we have no way to retrieve the data we sent within the link. When the app is indeed already installed we are however able to do this using `Intent.DataString`.

Our question is basically: *How do we retrieve this data after the user installs the app?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the pre-release version of Firebase Dynamic Links for Xamarin.Android and kind of guessing how to use it with the Android documentation. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is done through **deferred deep linking** which can only be done using a third party. [Branch](http://Branch.io) has an open source [Xamarin deep linking SDK](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/xamarin-branch-deep-linking) that should do this for you.